# Have you ever/do you ever?

Tags: sentence-meaning

What is the difference between:

> Do you ever go to the pop concert?

and

> Have you ever gone to the pop concert?

Comment: Though it is more likely that you would say "Do you ever go to *a* pop concert?" I think it is unlikely that you might go to the same concert on different occasions, unless it is a specific venue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you ever go to the pop concert?

In this sentence, **ever** is used to ask the person *how frequently/often/if* at all he/she goes to the pop concert, at any given point in time. Normal response to this question would be something like:

> - Yes, I go there every week/month.
> - Yes, I go there occasionally.
> - No, I really don't get the time.

Coming to your second question:

> Have you ever gone/been to the pop concert?

This is a more specific question. It asks the person about his going to the pop concert specifically in the past.

Responses to this question could be:

> - Yes, I went there last month/year.
> - No, I haven't been to the concert.

To point out the difference of this question from the first one - the second question (unlike the first one) doesn't consider the general interest of the person in going to pop concerts in his/her day-to-day life.